# Display Parent Values if Specified Child Values are NULL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 site connected to a mysql database and using entity framework (db first).

In my Products table, a parent item can have many child items. We use the parent items in this case as overviews or containers, aka the parent is PRODUCT-XYZ overview, and the children are it's variations (PRODUCT-XYZ-1-INCH, PRODUCT-XYZ-2-INCH, ...). The structure must remain this way because of how the accounting source has things organized.

Using linq, it's been easy to list products in a category, pull product info by specified id, etc. But I cannot wrap my head around how to accomplish the following using linq queries.

====================

## SCENARIO #1

Given ProductID of child, pull all child columns, overwrite a few specified columns with parent (derived from ParentID) if those columns are blank.

For example, given child with ID of 2, Description and DetailedDescription are null so the values of it's parent (ID of 1) are used.

====================

## SCENARIO #2

Same as scenario #1, but in a list situation. While listing all the products in CategoryID 1, if it's a parent, just use parent values, if it's a child and has null values in the Description, DetailedDescription columns, use those. If it's a child with it's own values, then use those.

TABLE: Products

```
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| ID | ParentID | ExternalID | Description | DetailedDescription |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 1  | NULL     | 3829       | Content     | Content             |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 2  | 1        | 4837       | NULL        | NULL                |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 3  | 1        | 9283       | Content     | Content             |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 4  | 1        | 6382       | NULL        | NULL                |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 5  | NULL     | 3234       | Content     | Content             |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 6  | 5        | 9283       | NULL        | NULL                |
------------------------------------------------------------------    
| 7  | 5        | 2983       | Content     | Content             |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TABLE: Categories

```
-------------------------------
| ID | ExternalID | Name      |
-------------------------------
| 1  | 2546       | Tools     | 
-------------------------------
| 2  | 3545       | Widgets   | 
-------------------------------
```

TABLE: Category_Product

```
--------------------------
| CategoryID | ProductID |
--------------------------
| 1          | 1         | 
--------------------------
| 1          | 2         | 
--------------------------
| 1          | 7         | 
--------------------------
```

====================

## ADDITIONAL NOTES

I've been pulling the details for a specific product like this:

```
Product product = (from p in db.Products.Include("Assets").Include("RelatedProducts")
                               where p.ID == id
                               select p).SingleOrDefault();
```

I pull a category with it's products using this:

```
Category category = (from cats in db.Categories.Include("SubCategories").Include("Products")
                           where cats.ID == id
                           select cats).SingleOrDefault();
```

Please let me know if I haven't provided enough information, even generic guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ProductVM
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Desc { get; set; }
   public string DetailDesc { get; set; }
   public List<CategoryVM> cats { get; set; }
}
public class CategoryVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string DetailDesc { get; set; }
}


 ProductVM product = new ProductVM();

  using (YourEntities context = new YourEntities ())
  {                 
      product = (from x in context.Parents
                 where x.Id == 1
                 select new ProductVM
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     Desc = x.Descr,
                     DetailDesc = x.DetailDesc
                  }).FirstOrDefault();

    product.Categegories = (from x in context.Children
                           where x.ParentId == product.Id
                          select new CategoryVM
                          {
                             Id = x.Id,
                             ParentId = (int)x.ParentId,
                             Desc = x.Descr == null ? product.Desc : x.Descr,
            DetailDesc = x.DetailDesc == null ? product.DetailDesc : x.DetailDesc
                            }).ToList();

           }
```

If you are unfamiliar with the `?` it is called the ternary operator. It's basically short hand for an if/else. In English the line of code reads..."If `x.Descr` is `null` then make the value of `Desc` equal to `product.Desc` else `Desc` equals `x.Desc`"

Your `ProductVM` will contain all the values of your Product and contain a List of its Categories, if x field is null, that particular category will take the value from Product

Edit: It looks like I got the Products - Categories relationship backwards, but this gives you the jist of what to do

Comment: I can definitely work with that, thanks. Flipped the Product and Category around and have run a few tests, seems to work well. I got stuck in the mindframe that everything needed to be all in one query. Much appreciated!